# Directory prwoling recursive functions isn't invoked

Tags: c, file, recursion, directory, unistd.h

One of the issues I've encountered whilst making a recursive directory lister is that a call after a directory check isn't invoked in the recursive function's stack.

```
void direct_crawl(int indent, char *cwd, STAT nstat)
{
    int i, i_in, count;
    struct direct **files;
    int file_comp();

    count = scandir(cwd, &files, file_comp, alphasort);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
       for (i_in = 0; i_in < indent; i_in++)
            printf("\t");
       printf("%s\n", files[i]->d_name);

       stat(files[i], nstat);

       if (S_ISDIR(nstat->st_mode) != 0)
            direct_crawl(indent + 1, files[i]->d_name, nstat)
     }
```

}

it goes up ONE subdirectory, but if those directories have subdirectories it just doesn't bother...so, could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Does your real code also misses error checking with such consequence?

Comment: Use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html). No need to reinvent it!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is that even in subdirectories you call `stat()` with just a filename, which is searched in the current directory and not in the subdirectory, so `stat()` fails. It may work if you call `chdir(cwd)` before and `chdir("..")` after the `for` loop.

Comment: Better yet, build (e.g. with `asprintf` or `snprintf`) the complete name of the file. But always skip `.` & `..` entries. And you should use `nftw`